# Sequelize — how to get associated model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I have two associated models (abbreviated for clarity)

```
const model = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
      fullName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
          len: [1,255]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
          User.hasMany(models.Meeting, {as: 'chairedMeetings', foreignKey: 'chairmanId'})
        }
      }
    }
  )

  return User
}
```

and

```
const model = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

  const Meeting = sequelize.define('Meeting', {
      title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
          len: [1,255]
        }
      }
    }, {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
          Meeting.belongsTo(models.User, {as: 'chairman'})
        }
      }
    }
  )

  return Meeting
}

module.exports = model
```

I create a new meeting, given an previously created user with `id = 1`, as follows:

```
const data = {
  title: 'Some amazing meeting title',
  chairmanId: 1
}

Meeting.create(data, {include: [{all: true, nested: true}]}).then(meeting => {
  const chairmanId = meeting.get('chairmanId') // ===> this is 1 as expected
  const chairman = meeting.get('chairman')     // ===> but this is undefined
}
```

How do I get sequelize to return the associated record without manually having to go through the associations and `findOne` them by `id`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out:

The solution is to do a [`reload`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/instance/#reloadoptions-promisethis) after creation.

```
Meeting.create(data, {include: [{all: true, nested: true}]}).then(meeting => {
  const chairmanId = meeting.get('chairmanId') // ===> this is 1 as expected
  meeting.reload({include: [{all: true, nested: true}]}).then(reloadedMeeting => {
    const chairman = reloadedMeeting.get('chairman') // ===> is a user!
  })
}
```

I guess sequelize doesn't automatically reload after creation in case you never actually care about the model you just created, and you just want to know it got saved.